# SSMS connect to azure failure

Tags: azure, ssms

I am connecting to azure database using ssms 17.9. i opened the firewall that allow remote connection for my office ip address. But there is a weird situation that my colleague pc ssms able to connect to azure database which mine cannot.

The error show in ssms is like below

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.NavigableItemBuilderDataReader.RunQuery()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.NavigableItemBuilderDataReader.Process()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.NavigableItemBuilderDataReader.get_PropertyNames()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.BuildDynamicItemWithQuery(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, String urnQuery, Boolean registerBuilder, Boolean registerBuiltItems)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.BuildDynamicItem(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, IFilterProvider filter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.Build(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, IFilterProvider filter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.Build(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, IFilterProvider filter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ObjectExplorerControl.BuildDataModel(SqlOlapConnectionInfoBase ci)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ObjectExplorerControl.GetHierarchy(SqlOlapConnectionInfoBase ci, String displayName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ConnectToServer(UIConnectionInfo connectionInfo, IDbConnection liveConnection, Boolean validateConnection)

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteReader(String sqlCommand, SqlCommand& command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataReader(String query, SqlCommand& command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.SetConnectionAndQuery(ExecuteSql execSql, String query)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataProvider(StringCollection query, Object con, StatementBuilder sb, RetriveMode rm)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillData(ResultType resultType, StringCollection sql, Object connectionInfo, StatementBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillDataWithUseFailure(SqlEnumResult sqlresult, ResultType resultType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.BuildResult(EnumResult result)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.GetData(EnumResult erParent)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)

===================================

A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=10054&LinkId=20476

---

Server Name: appletea.database.windows.net,1433
Error Number: 10054
Severity: 20
State: 0

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)

===================================

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I've tried reinstall ssms,visual studio and even format my pc. but none of the solution that i found working. So i am here to looking someone for help. thanks and appreciate if someone can tell me how to solve this.

Comment: I would try to connect with a different tool to see if it's a software or networking issue.  Try connecting using Azure Data Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @CSharpRocks hi, i manage to login through azure data studio. but when i try to expand the database folder, it show me this error: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.

Comment: @Keith did you ever get this work? I have the same issue.

Comment: @wilsjd too bad until now i not manage to find a working solution. Do let me know if you found any working solution. thanks

Comment: @Keith I have something working for me. See my attempts and that it finally worked for me here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224169/ssms-cant-connect-to-azure-database

Comment: @wilsjd hi,thanks. will check it out and update here.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the comments, but thought I would post here for future readers too. See my answer here for a solution that worked for me: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224169/ssms-cant-connect-to-azure-database

**Summary:** Essentially, I had the same problem, I downloaded IISCrypto and enabled all of the Ciphers.

https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Download

Answer (score 0):

After installing the "Docker Desktop on Windows", I get the same problem. Uninstalling the Docker Desktop on Windows, give me the relief.